# Apply Cividiscount to only one price.

Tags: cividiscount

We are using Civi 4.7.22 on Wordpress 4.8.22

We have an upcoming three day event with several price options.  Our full-price is $189.00 and we want to give members of our organization a $60.00 discount when they purchase the full-price ticket to the event. We do not want to give a discount to the lower priced tickets, whether the person is a member or not.

So far when using cividiscount, the discount price is applied to the entire price list and not just the full price.  I don't yet see an option for controlling this.  Does anyone know what I can do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a price set, you can set which line items the code is valid for by selecting the line items in the field 'Price Field Options' under 'Additional Options' when you setup the code. You still need to set the event it is valid for under the 'Discounts for Events' section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.  That solved it for me. I was not using a price set. I was manually entering the fees on the event configuration page.  It is working perfectly now.